# Replace several 0 in a col with average of 0 and subsequent row

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace consequent zeroes in a column with a value that is an average of these consequent zeros and the following value. Is there an elegant way to do that, instead of iterating all the rows one by one?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
dates=pd.date_range(start = dt.date(2019,1,1), end=dt.date(2019,1,18), freq='1D')
data=[3,1,3.3,0,0,6,2.7,3,4,2.1,0,0,0,0,0,12,8,7]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=dates, columns=['how it is now'])
df['how it should be']= [3,1,3.3,2,2,2,2.7,3,4,2.1,2,2,2,2,2,2,8,7]
```

Thanks.

Comment: it's a datetime

Comment: @DanielMesejo, see the import. It's just a date variable being instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
df.groupby(df['how it is now'].ne(0).iloc[::-1].cumsum())['how it is now'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Thanks! Some comments would be helpful. Right now it looks like magic to me. =)

Comment: @AntonZi what I did : create the groupby key using ne 0 so , the last none zero untile next none zero will be splited into different group , then we get the mean of those

Comment: Thanks, the solution is very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple boolean indexing and [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df.current.eq(0)  # find those that are zero
shift_mask = df.current.eq(0).shift().fillna(False)  # find those that are after a zero

# use numpy.where to set the elements where the mask is True otherwise keep the old value (df.current)
df['result'] = np.where(mask | shift_mask, df.current[mask | shift_mask].mean(), df.current)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
            current  result
2019-01-01      3.0     3.0
2019-01-02      1.0     1.0
2019-01-03      3.3     3.3
2019-01-04      0.0     2.0
2019-01-05      0.0     2.0
2019-01-06      6.0     2.0
2019-01-07      2.0     2.0
2019-01-08      3.0     3.0
2019-01-09      4.0     4.0
2019-01-10      2.1     2.1
2019-01-11      0.0     2.0
2019-01-12      0.0     2.0
2019-01-13      0.0     2.0
2019-01-14      0.0     2.0
2019-01-15      0.0     2.0
2019-01-16     12.0     2.0
2019-01-17      8.0     8.0
2019-01-18      7.0     7.0
```